# PIG - Filter or how to get in side of a bag or tuple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

AS you can see we can apply filter to the first one because, we can used aggregate on the  temperature. Now how do we apply  the second filter on STRINGS?

We are only trying to filter e with conditions clear and partly cloudy.

```
Weather = LOAD 'hdfs:/home/hduser/final/Weather.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
A = FOREACH Weather GENERATE (int)$0 AS year, (int)$1 AS month, (int)$2 AS day, (int)$4 AS temp, $14 AS cond, (double)$5 as dewpoint , (double)$10 as wind;


group_by_day = GROUP A BY (year,month,day);
```

Schema:

```
   {day: (year: int,month: int, day: int), temperature {(temp: int)},                   

   condition: {cond: bytearray)}, dewPoint: {(dewpoint: double)} windSpeed:

   {(wind: double)}}
```

Comment: what does `dump e` look like?

Comment: It has day,  filtered temperatures,  and (cloudy, mostly cloudy, clear)  In a tuple

Comment: `FILTER e BY condition == 'clear' OR condition== 'partly cloudy'`

Comment: in alias f, incompatible types in Equal operations or left had side : bag : tuple:(cond:bytearray) right hand side: chararray

Comment: @dedpo Can you post the entire script,sample data,desired output please? cond:bytearray tells me that the datatype is not correct.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind made some additions hopefully this will clear some stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast cond as chararray in the below statement.Since you have not specified the datatype in your load statement,all fields will be loaded as bytearray.That is the default datatype chosen by PigStorage.

```
A = FOREACH Weather GENERATE (int)$0 AS year, (int)$1 AS month, (int)$2 AS day, (int)$4 AS temp, (chararray)$14 AS cond, (double)$5 as dewpoint , (double)$10 as wind;
```

**EDIT**

I was able to get the results by use [BagToString](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToString.html) function.You can do the filtering in 1 step iteslf.

```
D = FILTER C BY (MIN(temperature) >= 60 AND MAX(temperature) <= 79) AND (BagToString(condition) == 'clear' OR BagToString(condition) == 'partly cloudy');
```

Or in your case

```
f = FILTER e BY BagToString(condition) == 'clear' OR BagToString(condition) == 'partly cloudy';
```

[image]

Comment: Hi after doing what you said it gave me " in alias f, incompativle types in Equal operations left hand side : bag : tuple(cond:chararray) right hand side: charyarray

Comment: try f = FILTER e BY condition.$0== 'clear' OR condition.$0 == 'partly cloudy'; its strange temperature.temp works in the previous filter statement.Without the sample data its hard to test it out

Comment: @dedpo Can you paste some sample data from this file hdfs:/home/hduser/final/Weather.csv ? Please no screenshot.

Comment: @dedpo I;ve edited the answer with the correct script and results using some test data